# Help with Django Installation

Tags: windows, django, installation

I'm trying to create my first project by typing in `THEFULLPATH\django-admin.py startproject mysite` but its not working. No 'mysite' directory created in my current directory. Instead it gives me a list of commands that is available with django-admin.py. See the below screenshot for more details.

[image]

Comment: And when you add `--traceback`?

Comment: Same result when I entered `django-admin.py startproject --traceback mysite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifically run the script with python, so:

```
python django-admin.py startproject
```

I'm not sure why it behaves like this, and it sure is annoying..

Answer (score 0):

The problem (as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701078/how-to-unset-django-settings-module-in-windows-vista) states), is documented [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11980). You need to unset the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

You can do this by typing:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=
```

at a DOS command prompt.