# How to unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in Windows Vista?

Tags: django, installation

I have this problem here: [Help with Django Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696831/help-with-django-installation)

The workaround seems to be here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11980

My problem is how do I unset the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with Django Installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696831/help-with-django-installation)

Answer (score 0):

With Vista or 7, you should have the `setx` command. The following command should remove the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable:

```
setx DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ""
```

You may need to add the `/M` flag at the end of the command.

The `setx` can only set the variable to empty, not delete it. So if setting it to empty does not work, [you could try using the GUI](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread5736.html). I'm just not sure if that's Vista or Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been so long anyway i have faced this issue recently that made me to post the way i fixed.

if you set

> set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="some of your settings file"

then you have to unset it via

> set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=

or if u did it  like

> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= "some of your settings file"

then try this

> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=